# discord.net.commands.dll either not found or missing assembly file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, discord.net

I am making a C# project in VS 2019. Everything worked and then I added discord, now when I run it I get:

[image]

If i include the dll in the folder, i get:

[image]

I have come to find out that this error usually means that there is 2 files with the same name.  How do I get around needing to add the dll but not being able to have the dll????

None of my other dll files have been needed to be added to the folder.

**Edit:**
I just got this to popup on the initial discord connection
[image]

**Edit 2:**
I have tried adding

```
<probing privatePath="lib" />
```

to my config file and added all the dll files to the lib folder, but I once again get the error expecting an assembly manifest but for a different dll.
[image]

Comment: Learn about assembly redirect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection

Comment: I'm really not sure what you did based on your description but there is no reason you should be adding dll files yourself to your project. Just install the Discord.Net package via nuget.

Comment: I did install it through nuget, but it still says that the file is missing.

Comment: @T.S. I'm not sure what it is I'm looking for with the assembly redirect?

Comment: @RobertKelley check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element

One of your components might be built against different version of assembly and this is why you see this. You can redirect and .net will allow substitution

Comment: I tried enabling auto-generate binding requests, but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: I added a new find to the question, when adding extra exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  I was downloading the files incorrectly.  I was reading the files and then writing them to the local instead of downloading the files directly.  This caused the manifest to each file to not be included.